# Creating uiviewcontroller as weak programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am creating uiviewcontroller in my one of the singleton like this.

```
BrowserVC *vc = [BrowserVC loadFromNib];
vc.titleName = @"Password Management";
[vc setData:@{@"url":url.absoluteString}];
vc.successBlock = ^(NSString *urlStr){
    if (![urlStr isEqualToString:url.absoluteString])
        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
```

Then, I got this usual error.

> Capturing 'vc' strongly in this block is likely to lead a retain
>   cycle.

To solve that warning, I have used either __Weak or __unsafe_unretained. Now, problem come in. My vc is released immediately after I initiate. I can't even set titleName. How shall I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is this

```
BrowserVC *vc = [BrowserVC loadFromNib];
vc.titleName = @"Password Management";
[vc setData:@{@"url":url.absoluteString}];

__weak __typeof(vc) weakVC = vc;

vc.successBlock = ^(NSString *urlStr){
    __typeof(vc) strongVC = weakVC;

    if (strongVC && ![urlStr isEqualToString:url.absoluteString])
        [strongVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
```

You create the view controller as you normally would but then you create a weak reference to the view controller and pass that into the block

Comment: ahh..like that. I don't know about this. Thanks for your help. It solve my issue.